# jquery ajax function with json

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi i am using this code to get contents from a json file but i am not able to show results

my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 50000,
    success: function(data, status){
    alert(data);    
    },
    error: function(){
        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
});
```

In google chrome i can see that the request status is 200 and data is loaded. here is the link from which i am copying code [The Link](http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/).... Any help!!!!

Thanks

Comment: did you want to use JSONP or just regular JSON with Ajax?  It looks like the service would return just JSON.

Comment: Cross Domain issues with just 'json'. The policy needs to be set otherwise.

Comment: yes the url returns just json

Comment: As far as I know, you need to use jsonp in order to make cross-domain calls (given that the server you're getting data from isn't the same on which you host your site). This would mean that you have to add the code given by jQuery trough GET. If it is however the same server, just use normal json and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes i know but the problem is the source which i am using just return json and not jsonp. Any suggestions of using any plugins etc so that i may read that url.

Comment: Any comments or anyother solution...

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because the `http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json` resource return a JSON response instead of JSONP ([difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)).

So you can't make cross-domain calls via ajax BUT you can create a some proxy script ON YOUR SERVER which will make it for you. Example:

cross-domain-call.php

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json');?>
```

And change your script to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/cross-domain-call.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 50000,
    success: function(data, status){
        console.log(data);    
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);    
        console.log(textStatus);    
        console.log(errorThrown);    
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue and I used the exact same hack :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to have access to remote webservice to convert it to JSONP, here is a solution using Yahoo's YQL as a proxy. YQL will retrieve file contents from any remote site and return as xml or jsonp.

Working DEmo  http://jsfiddle.net/Uh8cz/2/

You will notice the response object has additional properties created by YQL

```
var yqlBaseUrl = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';


var restUrl = 'http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json';
var yqlQuery = 'select * from json where url="' + restUrl + '" ';
var yqlFormat = 'format=json'
var jQueryCallback = '?'
var fullQueryUrl = yqlBaseUrl + yqlQuery + '&' + yqlFormat + '&' + jQueryCallback;

$.getJSON(fullQueryUrl, function(json) {
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json.query.results.json.json, null, ' ')
    $('body').append('<h1>Response</h1><pre>' + jsonString)
})  ​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the content of "user.json", wrap it around a function:

**user.json content:**

```
execute_jsonp({you_json)
```

**your javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 50000,
        success: function(data, status){
            data(); //execute the function that is sent
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });

    function execute_jsonp(json){ //recreate the function so you may access the json as a parameter
        alert(json);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps ;)